# Android - Save and recreate instance of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate

I'm new to android development, and I have come across this article, that shows how to restore the activity state : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

And I was wondering if it is the same about fragments, do I need to implement

> onSaveInstanceState and onCreate

the way they show, or do I also need to add something to the activity, since it is a fragment, and it doesn't work exactly like an activity.

Comment: A fragment has his own lifecycle , http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html